# How to complete build.gradle file in Android Studio for a Flutter app deployment?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[build.gradle_pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiKId.jpg)

[build.gradle_pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXIq2.jpg)

[build.gradle_pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqtrP.jpg)

[build.gradle_pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXdQK.jpg)

I am trying to generate an appbundle. I've got a key.jks file already ready to go. As far as I know, I've followed Flutter.dev/AndroidDeployment correctly? This is my first app deployment. Is manually changing the build.gradle file the best way to go? I know there's a UI structure element that has drop menus and such in Android Studio that I've tried to no success. Anyways, like I said, all I've done is follow Flutter.dev on Android deployment and now I'm stuck and I think my issue lies somewhere within build.gradle considering that it always shows red error lines under it. Can someone take a look at what I've got and lead me in the right direction? I've changed the private parts for obvious reasons.
Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with
flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")`
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.changed_text.techhelprelease"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['key']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['changedText']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['C:\\changedText\\key.jks'] ? file(keystoreProperties['C:\\changedText\\key.jks']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['changedText']
    }
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Please post the code within the question using code blocks instead of using images.

Comment: Here is the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['key']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['changedText']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['C:\\changedText\\key.jks'] ? file(keystoreProperties['C:\\changedText\\key.jks']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['changedText']
    }
}
```

Should have stayed default from Flutter.dev, which is this:

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
```

And then I figured out that I must have accidentally pasted the signature line where it didn't belong, which was throwing me an error every time. So this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.changed_text.techhelprelease"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```

Should not have the last line. Corrected:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.changed_text.techhelprelease"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
```